# Как отключить детализацию файла в phpstorm?

Tags: phpstorm

Коллеги, подскажите как отключить детализацию (структуру класса) при работе с файловой структурой проекта в phpstorm? Иногда это очень мешает в работе, приходится постоянно сворачивать, чтобы структура уместилась в окне.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Jlre.png

Comment: Спасибо @RomanGrinyov. Нашел еще ссылку по этому вопросу (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-structure-of-a-source-file.html)

Answer (score 0):

Нажми на шестерёнку SideBar -> Show Options Menu -> Show Members